# Plot cross sections of a function

Tags: plotting

I have been learning how to use *Mathematica* for the past few weeks, and recently I have been trying to recreate something along the lines of [this](http://media.wiley.com/Lux/54/204854.image0.jpg).

[image]

Given a function, I want to create a 3d plot of an object as if the bounded regions of the function were to be extruded upwards in a certain shape. From this I hope to find a basic volume, instead of integrating. How would I do this? I have seen `ParametricPlot3D`, but I haven't been able to create what I want with it.

Comment: Your diagram suggests that the triangle cross-sections are equilateral triangles. Is actually the case, or is it an artifact of the projection?

Comment: They should be equilateral triangles. Similar to the integration problems where you are asked to find the volume of objects. Here it would be find the volume of an object whose cross sections are equilateral triangles and base is defined by sinx and -sinx.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{v {u, Sin[u], 0} + (1 - v) {u, -Sin[u], 0},
  ConditionalExpression[v {u, Sin[u], 0} + (1 - v) {u, 0, Sin[u]},  0 <= u <= Pi],
  ConditionalExpression[v {u, -Sin[u], 0} + (1 - v) {u, 0, Sin[u]}, 0 <= u <= Pi],
  {u, 0, Sin[u]}},
  {u, -1, 4}, {v, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, White], Lighting -> "Neutral",
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1},
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, u], Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, v]},
  Mesh -> {Range[0, Pi, Pi/4], {0, 1}},
  MeshStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, Red], Directive[Thick, Blue]},
  PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> 500, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  Ticks -> {{Pi/2, Pi}, {-1/2, -1}, {1/2, 1}},
  PlotRangePadding -> .2,  AxesStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**Update:**  a first attempt to use `RegionPlot3D`:

```
RegionPlot3D[-Abs@Sin[x] <= Abs@y <= Abs@Sin[x] && z + Abs@y <= Abs@Sin[x] && 0 <= z,
 {x, 0, Pi}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, Pi + 1/2}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.6]], Lighting -> "Neutral",
 PlotPoints -> 35,
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, #3 &},
 Mesh -> {{.5, 1., 1.5, 2., 2.1, 2.2, 2.3}, {0.}, {0.}},
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thin, Gray], Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Thick, Blue]},
 Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Thick,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Ticks -> {{Pi/2, Pi}, {-1/2, -1}, {1/2, 1}},
 ImageSize -> 500, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 very nice indeed. It has even a hand drawn look!

Comment: thank you @chris. _hand-drawn_-look made with poor-man's built-in  _xkcd_-style (resize the cropped image):)